# How to Create a button to execute code when pressing enter or clicking the button?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have created a button.
right now the button only works after clicking the button.
what I want to do is, When I press the 'enter' key on the keyboard or click the button my code needs to be executed.

how to do that?

```js
const befoClick= document.querySelector('.befoClick');
const afteClick=document.querySelector('.afteClick');

befoClick.addEventListener('click',()=>{
    afteClick.classList.toggle('clicked'); 
 });
```

```css
body{
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
  height:100vh;  
}

button{
  width:200px;
  height:50px;
  font-size:20px;
  cursor: pointer;
  border:none;
   border-radius: 8px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%); 
}
.befoClick{
  background-color: rgb(74, 74, 255);
}

.afteClick{
   background-color: rgb(67, 255, 77);
  visibility: hidden;
}

.clicked{
    visibility: visible;
}

.bfrClick{
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class='allBtn'>
<div >
  <button class='befoClick'>CLICK ME</button>
  </div>
<div >
  <button class='afteClick'>CLICKED</button>
  </div>
  
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `keyup` event listener and then check the pressed key.

There are two event listeners so, I added a separate function.

```js
const befoClick= document.querySelector('.befoClick');
const afteClick=document.querySelector('.afteClick');

const toggleClass = () => afteClick.classList.toggle('clicked'); 

befoClick.addEventListener('click', toggleClass);
 
document.addEventListener('keyup', (event) => {
  if (event.key === 'Enter') {
    toggleClass();
  }
});
```

```css
body{
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
  height:100vh;  
}

button{
  width:200px;
  height:50px;
  font-size:20px;
  cursor: pointer;
  border:none;
   border-radius: 8px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%); 
}
.befoClick{
  background-color: rgb(74, 74, 255);
}

.afteClick{
   background-color: rgb(67, 255, 77);
  visibility: hidden;
}

.clicked{
    visibility: visible;
}

.bfrClick{
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class='allBtn'>
<div >
  <button class='befoClick'>CLICK ME</button>
  </div>
<div >
  <button class='afteClick'>CLICKED</button>
  </div>
  
  </div>
```

Comment: your script doesn't work on click for the addEventlistener as you also need to bind an eventListener to the other button or to listen to both buttons. However, using 2 buttons is a poor solution IMHO. The smart solution would be to only use one button and toggle the text aswell.

Comment: PS you can also use an array to make an eventListener listen for multiple events.

Comment: Could you please show me how to do it like that?

Answer (score 0):

we can use an array like `['click', 'keyup]` and then use `forEach` on the array to listen to both Events with the same `eventListener`.

However, if you use `Enter` it will trigger the `eventListener` twice as it recognizes the click and the Enter press itself. As such we need to run the script then also twice.

Then in the actual script, you can use `classList.toggle` to toggle between a clicked class to apply style changes.

Then you can toggle the `textContent` of the button between an array aswell.

```js
var eleButton = document.querySelector('.button'),
  buttonText = ['CLICK ME', 'CLICKED'],
  indexButtonText = 0;

['click', 'keyup'].forEach(el => {
  eleButton.addEventListener(el, function(e) {
    changeButton();
    if (e.key == 'Enter') {
      changeButton();
    }
  });
});

function changeButton() {
  indexButtonText = (indexButtonText == 0 ? 1 : 0);
  eleButton.classList.toggle('clicked');
  eleButton.textContent = buttonText[indexButtonText];
}
```

```css
body {
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
  height: 100vh;
}

button {
  width: 200px;
  height: 50px;
  font-size: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 8px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  background-color: rgb(74, 74, 255);
}

.clicked {
  background-color: rgb(67, 255, 77);
}
```

```html
<button class='button'>CLICK ME</button>
```